# How to get the hash of the signedAttrs for a PKCS7

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, pkcs#7

I am struggling because I need to manually verify the signature of an `PKCS7` file and the verification fails with the hash I get using the `PKCS7_digest_from_attributes()` method.

It appears that the signature is done on several signed attributes rather than this hash. I found a method called `cms_msgSigDigest()` that seems to do what I need but it is not callable using the `OpenSSL` *API*.

Thanks to guide me.